# "Better have it get fired at someone" - get fired?

Tags: grammar, verbs, get-be

I know "get" has so many meanings but I just do cannot figure out the right one here:

> If you establish a gun in Act 1, you better have it get fired at
>   somebody by Act 3.

Would it not work without the "get"? What does it express here exactly? It does not seem to be (to me) change of condition (as in get married) or a replacement for "be".

Comment: I don't know where you found this sentence, but I think it could have been written better. (It's not wrong, but it's not great, either.) _If you establish a gun in Act 1, you'd better have somebody fire it by Act 3._ The meaning changes slightly, but the advice to the playwright is largely the same. Another way (one that gets rid of the "get)": _If you establish a gun in Act 1, it had better be fired at someone by Act 3._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The gun got fired.

Applies the verb *fired* to gun, using the passive voice so that the subject is the patient (the gun) and the actor (whoever fired the gun) need not be stated.

Extending that:

> It got fired.

Use pronoun instead of noun.

> You had it get fired.

You caused it to pass that it got fired.

> You better have it get fired.

You are strongly advised to cause it to get fired.

Comment: The gun got fired, is it not "the gun was fired"? I am trying to understand what usage of "get" this is.

Comment: It can be either, *get* can be used to form the passive, as here. Some object to this use, but clearly whoever is paraphrasing Chekhov here does not. (And neither for that matter, do I, though the other forms are often nicer to the ear).

Comment: "The gun was fired" is the passive, isn't it? Or you mean the final construct? "You better have it fired" would not be enough I guess. I somehow cannot see the difference "The gun fired" "The gun got fired"

Comment: "The gun got fired" and "the gun was fired" are both equivalent passive forms. The final construct has more than one verb and mixes the passive and the active voice. "You better have it fired" is equivalent, and arguably better, or at least more formal. Search for "get passive" for more on this form of the passive.

Comment: Thank you! I just find it strange that someone says "You better have it get fired" instead of the shorter, equivalent version without the "get". At least if I understood correctly.

Comment: To a lot of people, it's the more common passive form. They'd understand the other form, and might even use it if they were consciously trying to be formal (but maybe not), but the "get" form was that they hear the most in their dialect, and so use the most.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to avoid 'get' entirely. But I think I would say:

'You had better ensure it gets fired by Act 3'